# O(n*logn) -- Not able to understand the prefix (n-1)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

I am confused with the below explanation in one of the google searches for merge sort

`T(n) = 2T(n/2) + (n-1)` This left side equation, if you solve, will resolve to `n*log(n)`

Here `2T(n/2)` is right, because each time we are breaking into the n elements array, into 2 parts...and splitting them further, until we reach a single element array.

In the merge part, at the most, we compare `n` elements at the worst case.
But, as shown in the above equation, it `n-1`. Not able to understand, why it is `n-1`.

Comment: Merging `n` elements requires `n-1` compares.  Try an examples.

Comment: Thanks . That’s right. I was thinking previously, if there are n elements.l, then there will be n comparisons. Got it now